# Webpack Dev Server stops on error originated in postcss-loader

Tags: css, reactjs, webpack, webpack-dev-server, postcss-loader

I'm using `webpack-dev-server` for development but after upgrading to `webpack 5` it just stops when `postcss-loader` can't parse css file.

I start dev server via `npx webpack-dev-server` and when I start typing new rule in `.css` webpack tries to rebuild my app but since I haven't finished typing, file contains incorrect css rule. So build fails due to `postcss-loader` throwing error `CssSyntaxError`. However that makes `webpack-dev-server` stop completely. Previously `webpack-dev-server` simply ignored failed builds and waited till `webpack` manages to successfully build my app.

I prepared git repo where this can be reproduced: https://github.com/s-shev/webpack-dev-server-stops

I'm using latest versions of `webpack`, `webpack-cli` and `webpack-dev-server`

I'd appreciate if anyone can say whether I'm doing something wrong or if it's a bug in `webpack-dev-derver`.

Here's my `webpack.config`:

```
const path = require("path");
const HtmlWebpackPlugin = require("html-webpack-plugin");

const devMode = process.env.NODE_ENV !== "production";

module.exports = {
  mode: devMode ? "development" : "production",
  devtool: devMode ? "eval-cheap-module-source-map" : "source-map",
  entry: path.resolve(__dirname, "./src/index"),
  devServer: {
    host: "0.0.0.0",
    port: 9000,
  },
  module: {
    rules: [
      {
        test: /\.tsx?$/,
        exclude: /node_modules/,
        use: { loader: "ts-loader" },
      },
      {
        test: /\.css$/,
        exclude: /node_modules/,
        use: ["style-loader", "css-loader", "postcss-loader"],
      },
    ],
  },
  resolve: {
    extensions: [".ts", ".tsx", ".js"],
    modules: ["./node_modules"],
  },
  plugins: [
    new HtmlWebpackPlugin({
      template: path.join(__dirname, "public", "index.html"),
    }),
  ],
};
```

and `pacakge.json`:

```
{
  "name": "webpack-dev-server-stops",
  "version": "1.0.0",
  "description": "",
  "private": true,
  "scripts": {
    "start": "webpack-dev-server"
  },
  "keywords": [],
  "author": "",
  "license": "ISC",
  "devDependencies": {
    "@types/react": "^18.0.15",
    "@types/react-dom": "^18.0.6",
    "css-loader": "^6.7.1",
    "html-webpack-plugin": "^5.5.0",
    "postcss-loader": "^7.0.0",
    "react": "^18.2.0",
    "react-dom": "^18.2.0",
    "style-loader": "^3.3.1",
    "ts-loader": "^9.3.1",
    "typescript": "^4.7.4",
    "typescript-plugin-css-modules": "^1.3.1",
    "webpack": "^5.73.0",
    "webpack-cli": "^4.10.0",
    "webpack-dev-server": "^4.9.3"
  }
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Turned out to be an issue in postcss. Updating postcss-loader to `7.0.1` fixed the issue.

https://github.com/webpack/webpack-dev-server/issues/4514